# Batch-file to rename files in a folder with prefix

Tags: batch-file

When working I often have to copy a template directory, which consists of multiple different file types, to a location on server that corresponds to a project I'm currently working on.

So, in a path

```
C:/Server/1010 Mr Customer/Housing
```

I have a couple of documents, for example

```
XX housing.dwg
XX data.doc
XX plan.dwg
```

Where "1010 Mr Customer" is a Project directory, and "Housing" is a template directory that I copy to project when I start working on a, for example, housing assignment. There are multiple template directories.

I want to create a batch file that will be copied n a Housing directory and rename every file in a way that it replaces "XX" with "1010 Mr Customer" in this folder.

So it should isolate the folder name in it's path, but not the first step above, because that one is always named "Housing" or some other template name.

The result would be this

```
C:/Server/1010 Mr Customer/Housing
1010 Mr Customer housing.dwg
1010 Mr Customer data.doc
1010 Mr Customer plan.dwg
renamer.bat
```

Thanks!

Comment: I will have a look at your question in the morning and help with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your response.

I've tried pasting it in a txt file, then named it renamer.cmd, as well as renamer.bat, but id didn't seem to work. I run windows 7 machine.

Here's the code that I've compiled from couple of other scripts I've found around here, and it seems to work so far.

Note: I've decided to leave out the number 1010.  I know it's frankensteined a bit, so to say, but I'm not looking for aestethics at this point.
Maybe you could look at it and point out if there's a possible problem?

so, the program works, when pasted in housing directory, like this:

```
C:/Server/1010 Mr Customer John second project/Housing
XX housing.dwg
XX data.doc
XX plan.dwg


Mr Customer second housing.dwg
Mr Customer second data.doc
Mr Customer second plan.dwg
```

and here's the code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET old=XX
for %%* in (..) do set new=%%~nx*
set new=%new:~5%
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.*') do (
  SET newname=%%f
  SET newname=!newname:%old%=%new%!
  move "%%f" "!newname!"
)
```

Thank you for help!

++

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to take all the files in directory `Housing` and rename to remove `XX` and include the previous folder name which in this case is `1010 Mr Customer` which will result in a name of `1010 Mr Customer Housing.*` This example only searches for `.dwg` and `.doc` files in the current directory. To add files, just add `,*.extention name` or to make if for all files in the dir, simply make it `.*`

***Note!!*** this script assumes that it will be in the 3rd directory as per your example.

**renamer.cmd**

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set mydir="%~p0"
set "mydir=%mydir:\=;%"
set "mydir=%mydir: =_%"

for /F "tokens=2 delims=;" %%b IN (%mydir%) DO (
 set name=%%b
 set name=!name:_= !
for %%i in (*.dwg,*.doc) do (set "file=%%i"
 set "remove=!file:~3!"
 if "!file:~0,3!"=="XX " echo move "!file!" "!name! !remove!")
 )
)
endlocal
```

This will take the previous folder name and store it as a variable called `%name%` take each file and store them in a variable called `%file%` remove the first 3 characters from filename, being `XX` (yes there is a whitespace in the removal) then we check if the files actually start with `XX` in order to not incorrectly rename other files, and if tested successfully, we do the rename.

***Note!*** this will echo the rename, to actually do the rename, remove the echo in the `if` statement line at the bottom. Also, I have not included any paths so unless you include paths, you need to place this script in the `Housing` directory. Then if your `XX` can be in either upper or lower case, you need to add `/I` after if to make it case insensitive.